# Survey Question - Not Seeing Success Message

Tags: craft3, form, error-message, validation

I am creating a survey for a client but when testing the survey, I am having trouble getting the Success Message or Error Message when complete ("Thank you for taking the survey" or "Error"). It is just a blank screen with no text. I am also not seeing the Submission in the back end... Any ideas?

Comment: We're going to need _far_ more information before anyone can reasonably be expected to answer your question as it stands. Please review and add more detail.

Comment: Hi Adrienne, can you share whether you are using a plugin for this? Can you share the code and methods you're using to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.